# How to Fix: getJSON function repeats the same string while in a FOR Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I'm trying to assign `src` attribute for `.poster` class of a specified id, I am trying to get that from TMDB API.
`movies` array is assigned by PHP and it doesn't affect anything
Inside the for loop when I `console.log` the `moviename`, it is logged correctly 
But when I write the `$.getJSON` function and `console.log` the `moviename` inside the function, it logs the last item of the array(`"Superman+Red+Son"`)

How can I fix it, Code is below
Thanks in advance.

```
movies = ["Star+Wars+Rise+Of+Skywalker","Lego+Movie","Lego+Movie+2+Second+Part","Superman+Red+Son"];
for (q of movies) {
    moviename = q.replace(/\u002B/g, "");
    console.log(moviename);
    $.getJSON('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=' + key + '&query=' + q + '', function (data) {
        console.log(moviename);
        poster = data.results[0].poster_path;
        posterloc = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342' + poster;
        $('#' + moviename + ' .poster').attr('src', posterloc);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this issue was caused by not defining variables using `let`,`var` or `const`